# How to merge www domains with non www domains in Google Analytics report

Tags: google-analytics

I’ve encounter an issue with google analytics,
I’ve created a custom report, for my domain with these parameters:

metric : pageviews
dimension: hostname
filters: none

The results are the table below which is exactly what I want, except that GA dissociates hostnames with www and without www.

[image]

In my example, I want the first and the second rows should be together and the value should be 651. 
How can I do this in a custom report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up an Advanced Filter as such (depending on whether you want the www or not). Assuming the latter (ie. you want to remove the www):

```
Field A - Extract A: Hostname; ^(www\.)?(.*)
Field B - Extract B: {leave blank}; {leave blank}
Output to - Constructor: Hostname; $A2
```

So in field A, you look for the hostname and break it down into the "www." part, if it exists, and the "domain.com" part (for example), and then the filter returns "domain.com".

Comment: Thanks for your help nguyen, I didn't understand, I need to add two filters ?

Comment: Thanks for your help nguyen, I want to apply the filter for all my hostnames not only carrosserie-rouze.com. Like you said I will need to use regex but I don't know can I do in order to merge all www.hosts.com with those without www (host.com)

Comment: Hi Jaybe, I modified my answer to make it generic.

Comment: is it something like that ? I get 0 result with this.

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=798290screenshotbynimbus.png

Comment: No, you need to set it up in an Advanced Filter. So in your Admin UI, go to the View > Filters, and set it up there. So click on New Filter, and then select Custom Filter > Advanced, and then fill it in as I have indicated.

Comment: I've manage to create a custom filter thanks to you, but i can't add this custom filter to my custom report. http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=193370screenshotbynimbus1.png

Comment: The filters cannot change past data but going forward you should see the changes. You don't have to do anything to your custom reports. The filter will be applied automatically.

Comment: Thank you ! I understand, I can't change the result of my custom report. If I want to merge those results I Need to do a PHP script for example.

Comment: Hmm... you should not have to merge in PHP... the merges should happen in your standard analytics reports as the filter is automatically applied.